# Input wont pass to variable

Tags: php, date, variables, transfer

been having trouble getting an input passed into a variable. My html is

```
<form  id="checkform" action="DateTest.php" method = "post">

    From Date:<label for="date"></label><br />
    <input id="date" type = "date" name = "date" placeholder = "Date" autocomplete="off" /><br />

    Until Date:<label for="date1"></label><br />
    <input id="date1" type = "date" name = "date1" placeholder = "Date" autocomplete="off" /><br />

    <input class="submit" title="submit" type = "submit" value = "Submit" name = "Submit"/><br />

</form> 
</div>
```

my php is

```
<?php
$fromDate = isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : 0;
$toDate = isset($_POST['date1']) ? $_POST['date1'] : 0;

var_dump($fromDate);
var_dump($toDate);

$dateMonthYearArr = array();
$fromDateTS = strtotime($fromDate);
$toDateTS = strtotime($toDate);

for ($currentDateTS = $fromDateTS; $currentDateTS <= $toDateTS; $currentDateTS += (60 *   60 * 24)) {
$currentDateStr = date("d-m-Y",$currentDateTS);
$dateMonthYearArr[] = $currentDateStr;
}

echo  "<pre>";
print_r($dateMonthYearArr);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This was printing an empty array, so i dumped after the transfer and it shows `$fromDate` being passed as directed but shows `$toDate` as an empty integer.

Comment: And if you `var_dump($_POST);` is `date1` missing there as well?

Comment: yeah, only date is showing up. super confused!

Answer (score 0):

This was fine the morning after, didn't change a thing, must have been a glitch.